# Fatal Error Call to a member function registry() in observer in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.0

```
<?php namespace Namespace\Mymodule\Observer;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;
use Namespace\Mymodule\Helper\Data as DataHelper;

abstract class AbstractCartActionObserver
{
    /**
     * @var DataHelper
     */
    protected $_helper;

    /**
     * @var CheckoutSession
     */
    protected $_checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @var Registry
     */
    protected $_registry;

    /**
     * @param DataHelper $dataHelper
     * @param CheckoutSession $checkoutSession
     * @param Registry $registry
     */
    public function __construct(
        DataHelper $dataHelper,
        CheckoutSession $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry){
        $this->_helper = $dataHelper;
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->_registry = $registry;
    }

    /**
     * Fired by checkout_cart_product_update_after event
     *
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item[] $items
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _processQuoteItemsChange($items)
    {
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $quoteItem
         */

        $productsToAdd = $this->_registry->registry('gtm_products_addtocart');
        if (!$productsToAdd) {
            $productsToAdd = [];
        }

        $productsToRemove = $this->_registry->registry('gtm_products_to_remove');
        if (!$productsToRemove) {
            $productsToRemove = [];
        }
       $lastValues = [];

        if ($this->_checkoutSession->hasData(DataHelper::CART_PRODUCT_QUANTITIES)) {
            $lastValues = $this->_checkoutSession->getData(DataHelper::CART_PRODUCT_QUANTITIES);
        }

        foreach ($items as $quoteItem) {

            if ($quoteItem->getParentItem()) {
                continue;
            }
            $oldQty = isset($lastValues[$quoteItem->getId()]) ? $lastValues[$quoteItem->getId()] : 0;
            $qty = $quoteItem->isDeleted() ? 0 : $quoteItem->getQty();
            if ($qty > $oldQty) {
                $productsToAdd[] = [
                    'product' => $quoteItem->getProduct()->getSku(),
                    'quantity' => $qty - $oldQty,
                ];
            } elseif ($qty < $oldQty) {
                $productsToRemove[] = [
                    'product' => $quoteItem->getProduct()->getSku(),
                    'quantity' => $oldQty - $qty,
                ];
            }
        }

        $this->_registry->unregister('gtm_products_addtocart');
        $this->_registry->register('gtm_products_addtocart', $productsToAdd);


        $this->_registry->unregister('gtm_products_to_remove');
        $this->_registry->register('gtm_products_to_remove', $productsToRemove);


        $this->_checkoutSession->unsetData(DataHelper::CART_PRODUCT_QUANTITIES);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

This one is another class i am calling function of abstract class :

```
class CartAddObserver extends AbstractCartActionObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * Fired by sales_quote_product_add_after event
     *
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $items = $observer->getEvent()->getItems();
        $this->_processQuoteItemsChange($items);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: please share your full code to understand your issue.

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya I added full code please review and tell where i am mistaking while creating registry

Comment: This is not the full code. I see your class is abstract. This means it is never instantiated. This means you are never calling methods directly from this class. In case you have a class that extends the one you posted, post that one too.

Comment: And maybe the file & line where the error is thrown

Comment: Error is throwing on this line   $productsToAdd = $this->_registry->registry('gtm_products_addtocart');

Comment: Code looks good to me. May be you need to try flushing cache or removing generation.

Answer (score 0):

Try Merging two codes and remove the AbstractCartActionObserver. comment if you still get the same error.

```
class CartAddObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
 /**
     * @var DataHelper
     */
    protected $_helper;

    /**
     * @var CheckoutSession
     */
    protected $_checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @var Registry
     */
    protected $_registry;

    /**
     * @param DataHelper $dataHelper
     * @param CheckoutSession $checkoutSession
     * @param Registry $registry
     */
    public function __construct(
        DataHelper $dataHelper,
        CheckoutSession $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry){
        $this->_helper = $dataHelper;
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->_registry = $registry;
    }

    /**
     * Fired by sales_quote_product_add_after event
     *
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $items = $observer->getEvent()->getItems();
        $this->_processQuoteItemsChange($items);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Fired by checkout_cart_product_update_after event
     *
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item[] $items
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _processQuoteItemsChange($items)
    {
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $quoteItem
         */

        $productsToAdd = $this->_registry->registry('gtm_products_addtocart');
        if (!$productsToAdd) {
            $productsToAdd = [];
        }

        $productsToRemove = $this->_registry->registry('gtm_products_to_remove');
        if (!$productsToRemove) {
            $productsToRemove = [];
        }
       $lastValues = [];

        if ($this->_checkoutSession->hasData(DataHelper::CART_PRODUCT_QUANTITIES)) {
            $lastValues = $this->_checkoutSession->getData(DataHelper::CART_PRODUCT_QUANTITIES);
        }

        foreach ($items as $quoteItem) {

            if ($quoteItem->getParentItem()) {
                continue;
            }
            $oldQty = isset($lastValues[$quoteItem->getId()]) ? $lastValues[$quoteItem->getId()] : 0;
            $qty = $quoteItem->isDeleted() ? 0 : $quoteItem->getQty();
            if ($qty > $oldQty) {
                $productsToAdd[] = [
                    'product' => $quoteItem->getProduct()->getSku(),
                    'quantity' => $qty - $oldQty,
                ];
            } elseif ($qty < $oldQty) {
                $productsToRemove[] = [
                    'product' => $quoteItem->getProduct()->getSku(),
                    'quantity' => $oldQty - $qty,
                ];
            }
        }

        $this->_registry->unregister('gtm_products_addtocart');
        $this->_registry->register('gtm_products_addtocart', $productsToAdd);


        $this->_registry->unregister('gtm_products_to_remove');
        $this->_registry->register('gtm_products_to_remove', $productsToRemove);


        $this->_checkoutSession->unsetData(DataHelper::CART_PRODUCT_QUANTITIES);
        return $this;
    }
}
```